# Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo with my DrawerView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-fragments

After attempting to run my code on my device(Nexus 4) and it crashing repeatedly,I searched the forums for answers,I have tried re factoring my code into a new Android Project, I have also removed the Android Private Dependencies from my project build-path and I have also Cleaned my code close to 15 times within the last 3 hours. I believe something maybe wrong with how I'm compiling my project main.Java and whatnot.I’m just trying to learn so if you can point me into the right direction that would be great.

MainActivity.Java

```
   04-04 04:21:06.403: E/AndroidRuntime(2430): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    04-04 04:21:06.403: E/AndroidRuntime(2430): Process: com.foobar.app, PID: 2430
    04-04 04:21:06.403: E/AndroidRuntime(2430): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.foobar.app/com.foobar.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.foobar.app.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.foobar.app-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.foobar.app-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    04-04 04:21:06.403: E/AndroidRuntime(2430):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
    04-04 04:21:06.403: E/AndroidRuntime(2430):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
    04-04 04:21:06.403: E/AndroidRuntime(2430):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
    04-04 04:21:06.403: E/AndroidRuntime(2430):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
    04-04 04:21:06.403: E/AndroidRuntime(2430):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    04-04 04:21:06.403: E/AndroidRuntime(2430):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    04-04 04:21:06.403: E/AndroidRuntime(2430):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    04-04 04:21:06.403: E/AndroidRuntime(2430):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    04-04 04:21:06.403: E/AndroidRuntime(2430):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    04-04 04:21:06.403: E/AndroidRuntime(2430):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    04-04 04:21:06.403: E/AndroidRuntime(2430):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    04-04 04:21:06.403: E/AndroidRuntime(2430):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    04-04 04:21:06.403: E/AndroidRuntime(2430): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.foobar.app.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.foobar.app-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.foobar.app-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    04-04 04:21:06.403: E/AndroidRuntime(2430):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    04-04 04:21:06.403: E/AndroidRuntime(2430):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
    04-04 04:21:06.403: E/AndroidRuntime(2430):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
    04-04 04:21:06.403: E/AndroidRuntime(2430):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
    04-04 04:21:06.403: E/AndroidRuntime(2430):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
    04-04 04:21:06.403: E/AndroidRuntime(2430):     ... 11 more
```

ActivityManifest.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.foobar.app" >

        <uses-feature
            android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
            android:required="true" />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                android:value="AIzaSyCblB2SWMJ6E0dfQSJ_W21gZ3FRNaobvIg" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

            <activity
                android:name="com.foobar.app.MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name="com.foobar.app.MapActivity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_map" >
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name="com.foobar.app.GPSActivity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_gps" >
            </activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: post your layout xml and MainActivity class

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the activity name in manifest as

```
 android:name=".MainActivity"
```

instead of

```
android:name="com.foobar.app.MainActivity"
```

and do a clean and rebuild your project.

If this doesn't workout try renaming the package name, it should also update the manifest.

Comment: ive tried this and it doesnt work,says there is an error renaming the the package.

Comment: Try creating new project with proper package name